# function parameters is getting undefined

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I'm hitting the enter button, the `console.log` is printing but `(socketId, msg)` is showing `undefined`. what i'm doing wrong here please help me thanks in advance

```
const callComponent = ({
  handleSendMessage
}) => {

  function handleMessage(socketId, msg) {
    console.log('chat open clicked', socketId, msg)
    handleSendMessage(socketId, msg)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = event => {
      if (event.code === "Enter" || event.code === "NumpadEnter") {
        console.log("Enter key was pressed. Run your function.");
        event.preventDefault();
        handleMessage(socketId, msg)
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
    };
  }, []);
  //...
}
```

Comment: where are `socketId` and `msg` from?

Comment: Where are the arguments defined that are passed to `handleMessage(socketId, msg)` in the `listener`? The `useEffect` also appears to be an invalid React hook use. React hooks can only be called in Function components and custom hooks.

Answer (score 0):

`handleMessage` function inside `useEffect` has no access to `sockedId` and `msg`. Function parameters are passed, thus must be within the scope that calls the function.